# How to improve libevent bufferevent_write performance

Tags: c++, network-programming, epoll, libevent

For my test case, only send "00" message by `bufferevent_write`.
case 1: 20,000 tcp connections, and send "00" to each every 10s, it will cost 0.15s.
case 2: only 1 tcp connection, and send "00" 20,000 times every 10s, it will cost 0.015s.

Please give me some suggestions to improve `bufferevent_write` performance.

I just wanna as fast as possible, and wonder that, if bufferevent_write is async, why send 20k message to 1 tcp is much faster than send 1 msssage to 20k tcp.

```
CPU info:
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              16
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-15
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  8
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               85
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8269CY CPU @ 2.50GHz
Stepping:            7
CPU MHz:             2500.000
BogoMIPS:            5000.00
Hypervisor vendor:   KVM
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1024K
L3 cache:            36608K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-15
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves arat avx512_vnni

Memory info:
32G
```

the whole test case

```cpp
#include <event2/buffer.h>
#include <event2/bufferevent.h>
#include <event2/event.h>
#include <event2/listener.h>
#include <event2/thread.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

#include <atomic>
#include <cerrno>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <set>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

static event_base *kEventBase{nullptr};
static evconnlistener *kListener{nullptr};
static std::set<bufferevent *> kSessions{};
static std::mutex kSessionsMutex{};
static std::atomic_bool kRunning{false};

static void stop() {
    kRunning = false;
    if (kListener != nullptr) {
        evconnlistener_disable(kListener);
        std::cout << "normal listener stopped" << std::endl;
    }
    struct timeval local_timeval = {1, 0};
    if (kEventBase != nullptr) { event_base_loopexit(kEventBase, &local_timeval); }
}

static void handler(int sig) {
    std::cout << "get signal: " << sig << std::endl;
    stop();
}

static void ReadCallback(bufferevent *event, void *) {
    auto buffer = evbuffer_new();
    evbuffer_add_buffer(buffer, bufferevent_get_input(event));
    auto data_size = evbuffer_get_length(buffer);
    char data[data_size + 1];
    bzero(data, data_size + 1);
    evbuffer_remove(buffer, data, data_size);
    evbuffer_free(buffer);
    std::cout << "get data: " << data << std::endl;
}

static void EventCallback(bufferevent *event, short events, void *) {
    if (events & BEV_EVENT_EOF) {
        std::cout << "socket EOF" << std::endl;
    } else if (events & BEV_EVENT_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "socket error: " << evutil_socket_error_to_string(EVUTIL_SOCKET_ERROR());
    } else if (events & BEV_EVENT_TIMEOUT) {
        std::cout << "socket read/write timeout" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "unhandled socket events: " << std::to_string(events) << std::endl;
    }

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> local_lock_guard{kSessionsMutex};
        kSessions.erase(event);
        bufferevent_free(event);
    }
}

static void listenerCallback(evconnlistener *, evutil_socket_t socket, sockaddr *, int, void *) {
    bufferevent *event =
        bufferevent_socket_new(kEventBase, socket, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE | BEV_OPT_THREADSAFE);

    if (event == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "create buffer event failed" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    int enable = 1;
    setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&enable, sizeof(enable));
    setsockopt(socket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_QUICKACK, (void *)&enable, sizeof(enable));

    bufferevent_setcb(event, ReadCallback, nullptr, EventCallback, nullptr);
    bufferevent_enable(event, EV_WRITE | EV_READ);

    kSessions.emplace(event);
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    signal(SIGTERM, handler);
    signal(SIGINT, handler);

    evthread_use_pthreads();

    // init
    kEventBase = event_base_new();
    if (kEventBase == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "cannot create event_base_miner_listener_" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    sockaddr_in local_sin{};
    bzero(&local_sin, sizeof(local_sin));
    local_sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local_sin.sin_port = htons(1800u);
    local_sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    kListener = evconnlistener_new_bind(kEventBase,
                                        listenerCallback,
                                        nullptr,
                                        LEV_OPT_REUSEABLE | LEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE,
                                        -1,
                                        reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(&local_sin),
                                        static_cast<int>(sizeof(local_sin)));
    if (kListener == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "cannot create normal listener" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    kRunning = true;
    std::thread thread_send_message([]() {
        while (kRunning) {
            {
                // case 1: If send to 20,000 tcp connection, and send "00" for each, it will cost 0.15s.
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> local_lock_guard{kSessionsMutex};
                std::clock_t clock_start = std::clock();
                for (auto &it : kSessions) { bufferevent_write(it, "00", 2); }
                std::cout << "send message to all done, client count: " << kSessions.size()
                          << ", elapsed: " << std::clock() - clock_start << std::endl;
            }
            {
                // case 2: If send to 1 tcp connection, and send "00" 20,000 times, it will cost 0.015s.
//                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> local_lock_guard{kSessionsMutex};
//                for (auto &it : kSessions) {
//                    std::clock_t clock_start = std::clock();
//                    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; ++i) { bufferevent_write(it, "00", 2); }
//                    std::cout << "send message 20k times done, elapsed: " << std::clock() - clock_start
//                              << std::endl;
//                }
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
        }
    });

    event_base_dispatch(kEventBase);

    if (thread_send_message.joinable()) { thread_send_message.join(); }
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> local_lock_guard{kSessionsMutex};
        for (auto &it : kSessions) { bufferevent_free(it); }
        kSessions.clear();
    }
    if (kListener != nullptr) {
        evconnlistener_free(kListener);
        kListener = nullptr;
    }
    if (kEventBase != nullptr) {
        event_base_free(kEventBase);
        kEventBase = nullptr;
    }
}
```

the minimal reproducible example

```
// case 1: 20,000 tcp connections, and send "00" for each every 10s, it will cost 0.15s.
std::clock_t clock_start = std::clock();
for (auto &it : kSessions) { bufferevent_write(it, "00", 2); }
std::cout << "send message to all done, client count: " << kSessions.size()
          << ", elapsed: " << std::clock() - clock_start << std::endl;
```

```
// case 2: only 1 tcp connection, and send "00" 20,000 times every 10s, it will cost 0.015s.
for (auto &it : kSessions) {
    std::clock_t clock_start = std::clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20000; ++i) { bufferevent_write(it, "00", 2); }
    std::cout << "send message 20k times done, elapsed: " << std::clock() - clock_start
              << std::endl;
}
```

strace of case 1:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 56.32   29.519892           9   3135415    408444 futex
 20.53   10.762191           7   1490532           epoll_ctl
 15.25    7.992391          11    715355           writev
  3.98    2.086553       45360        46           nanosleep
  1.86    0.973074          11     85273         1 epoll_wait
  0.62    0.324022           8     39267     19266 accept4
  0.58    0.305246           6     48721           read
  0.55    0.286858           6     48762           write
  0.30    0.154980           4     40004           setsockopt
  0.01    0.006486           5      1216           mprotect
  0.01    0.002952          21       143           madvise
  0.00    0.001018           7       152           brk
  0.00    0.000527           6        94           clock_gettime
  0.00    0.000023           3         8           openat
  0.00    0.000021          21         1           mremap
  0.00    0.000010           0        22           mmap
  0.00    0.000007           1         9           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         8           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0         3           munmap
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           rt_sigaction
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           ioctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           readv
  0.00    0.000000           0         8         8 access
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           socket
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           bind
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           listen
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           clone
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           getuid
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           getgid
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           geteuid
  0.00    0.000000           0         4           getegid
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           set_robust_list
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           eventfd2
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           epoll_create1
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           pipe2
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           prlimit64
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00   52.416251               5605075    427719 total
```

strace of case 2:

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
normal listener stopped
 66.66    0.151105           7     22506      3469 futex
  9.74    0.022084           6      3709         1 epoll_wait
  9.54    0.021624           4      5105           epoll_ctl
  9.47    0.021466           8      2550           writev
  2.47    0.005598           4      1263           write
  1.70    0.003857           3      1246           read
  0.18    0.000409          18        23           nanosleep
  0.09    0.000197           4        46           clock_gettime
  0.03    0.000068           4        16           mprotect
  0.02    0.000035           2        21           mmap
  0.01    0.000024           8         3           munmap
  0.01    0.000019          10         2         1 accept4
  0.01    0.000018           5         4           setsockopt
  0.01    0.000015           8         2           set_robust_list
  0.01    0.000014           4         4           rt_sigaction
  0.01    0.000014           4         4           geteuid
  0.01    0.000013           3         4           getgid
  0.01    0.000012           3         4           getuid
  0.01    0.000012           3         4           getegid
  0.00    0.000011           1         8           fstat
  0.00    0.000010          10         1           socket
  0.00    0.000008           8         1           clone
  0.00    0.000007           2         3           brk
  0.00    0.000007           7         1           pipe2
  0.00    0.000006           1         7           openat
  0.00    0.000006           6         1           epoll_create1
  0.00    0.000005           1         8         8 access
  0.00    0.000005           5         1           bind
  0.00    0.000005           5         1           eventfd2
  0.00    0.000005           5         1           prlimit64
  0.00    0.000004           1         7           close
  0.00    0.000004           4         1           listen
  0.00    0.000003           3         1           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000003           3         1           arch_prctl
  0.00    0.000003           3         1           set_tid_address
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           execve
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.226676                 36561      3479 total
```

Comment: 150 ms for blatting out 20k two-byte(+overhead) TCP packets is not bad. Even better if that includes the time it takes to open said connections!

Comment: @Botje, not include the time open said connection, after 20k connection already, then send "00" to all every 10s

Comment: You will need to provide your test program so people can tell you how to improve it.

Comment: What are your performance requirements? Sending out 20K TCP packets in 150ms isn't particularly slow

Comment: @AlanBirtles I just wanna as fast as possible, and wonder that, if bufferevent_write is async, why send 20k message to 1 tcp is faster than send 1 msssage to 20k tcp

Comment: @Botje code added done

Comment: Can you run this code under strace and look at the send calls? I would not be surprised if case 1 does 20,000 calls for two bytes each and case 2 only does 30 calls for 1400 bytes or so. Context switches are cheap but not free.

Comment: At the TCP layer too, 20k 2 byte messages on a single socket won't generate 20k packets but using multiple sockets definitely will

Comment: What is your context? What kind of program are you coding? For a [top500](https://top500.org/) supercomputer, or just on a Linux laptop? Without more context and a real [mre], **your question is not clear**

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'v added the server info

Comment: @Botje I'v added strace stats info

Comment: See the difference in the amount of writev calls and the total time taken.

Answer (score 2):

> How to improve libevent bufferevent_write performance

**Read the documentation of [libevent](https://libevent.org/)**, study its source code, and consider other event loop libraries like [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/), [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) etc....

### Be aware of several points. I assume a modern Linux/x86-64 system.

- you could profile your open source event loop library (e.g. by compiling it from source code with a recent [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and [using](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `-pg -O2` flags, then [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and/or [gprof(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html) and/or [perf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf.1.html) and/or [time(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) (and also [top(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html), [ps(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), [netstat(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/netstat.8.html), [ip(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html), [ifconfig(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ifconfig.8.html), [tcpdump(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tcpdump.8.html), [xosview](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xosview) to **observe your *entire* Linux system**). Of course read [time(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [epoll(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) and [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)
- [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) is introducing some overhead, [IP routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_routing) adds more overhead, and the typical [Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) packet has at least hundreds of bytes (and dozens of bytes of overhead). You certainly want to [send(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) or [recv(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) several hundred bytes at once. **Sending short `"00"` messages** (of about four bytes of useful payload) **is inefficient**. Ensure that your application send messages of hundreds of bytes at once. You might consider some [JSONRPC](https://jsonrpc.org/) approach (and of course *design your protocol at a higher level* with fewer but bigger messages triggering each more complex behavior) or some [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) one. A way to send fewer but higher-level messages is to embed some interpreter like [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Lua](https://lua.org/) and send higher level script chunks or requests (like [NeWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeWS) did in the past, and [PostgreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) or [exim](https://exim.org/) do today)
- for short and small communications prefer running a few processes or threads on the *same* computer and use [mq_overview(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mq_overview.7.html), [pipe(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [fifo(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), [unix(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), avoiding Ethernet.
- Most computers are in 2020 [multi-core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor), and with care, you could use [Pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) or [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) (with one thread running on each core, so at least 2 or 4 different threads on a laptop, or a hundred threads on a powerful Linux server). You'll need some synchronization code (e.g. [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) with [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) or [Pẗhread mutexes](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#Mutexes)....)
- be aware of the [C10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem), and **take inspiration from *existing* open source server programs or libraries** such as [lighttpd](https://lighttpd.org/), [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt), [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), [REDIS](https://redis.io/), [Vmime](https://www.vmime.org/), [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) (and study their source code, and **observe their runtime behavior** with [gdb(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gdb.1.html) and/or [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [ltrace(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html))
- **the network might be the bottleneck** (then you won't be able to improve your code to gain performance; you'll need some change in your software architecture). Read more about [cloud computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing), [distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing), [XDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation), [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1), [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer),  [Web services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/), [π-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0-calculus)

Notice that:

```
static void handler(int sig) {
   std::cout << "get signal: " << sig << std::endl;
   stop();
}
```

if used with [signal(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) is against the rules of [signal-safety(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) so you might use the [pipe(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to self-process trick as [suggested by Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html) or consider using the Linux specific [signalfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) system call.

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) then [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [socket(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) and [tcp(7)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html).